# ORA-00060: Deadlock Trace file query found but can we get its parameter values

Tags: oracle, multithreading, stored-procedures, database-deadlocks

As this ORA-00060 is quite famous and I too have analyzed it in past and have solved a few of them in past. In my case I have ensured there is no common update from multiple session, still the error was occurring, and for such solutions I have used to increase the initrans and frequent commit in the concurrent transactions have helped me to solve it.
Now in another program again I saw the ORA-00060. Then I analyze the .trc file. There it is showing the merge query running from two session which is causing deadlock. This query has bind parameters. I wanted to know the values of this bind parameter. Because if by any bug if this binding parameter is same from the two session then it will be obvious that the two sessions are updating the same records, and eventually causing the deadlock.
Where I am struggling is that I am not able to see any way to get the value of these bind parameter in the .trc file. The call stack trace in the .trc file does have some blocks but very difficult to figure out where and what is the value of this parameter when the deadlock graph was created. **Does anyone know whether it is possible to get the bind parameter values from .trc file for the queries causing the deadlock?** I have started putting the log in the code so that next time when it occurs I will get that from normal logs.

Deadlock graph:
------------Blocker(s)-----------  ------------Waiter(s)------------

`Resource Name                             process session holds waits serial  process session holds waits serial TX-0012000B-0004A991-00000000-00000000        193     203     X         7643     195     583           S  11914 TX-000F000E-000871FC-00000000-00000000        195     583     X        11914     193     203           S   7643`

The query (table/column names I have changed) is:

```
----- Information for waiting sessions -----
Session 203:
sid: 203 ser: 7643 audsid: 38682755 user: 151/SCHMEA1
...
pid: 193 O/S info: user: grid, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 11010512
image: oracle@hostname
client details:
...
application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
current SQL:
MERGE INTO TABLE_A TA USING ZPD_TABL2 ZPD ON (TA.COY=ZPD.COY AND TA.COL2=ZPD.COL2 AND TA.TRXNO=ZPD.TRXNO AND (TA.COL3 = ' ' OR TA.COL3 IS NULL OR TA.COL3 = 'I') AND ZPD.THREADNO=:B1 ) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TA.COL3 = 'Y', TA.USRPRF=:B3 , TA.JOBNM=:B2 , TA.DATIME=LOCALTIMESTAMP

Session 583:
sid: 583 ser: 11914 audsid: 38682758 user: 151/VM1DTA
...
pid: 195 O/S info: user: grid, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 58064926
image: oracle@hostname
client details:
..
application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
current SQL:
MERGE INTO TABLE_A TA USING ZPD_TABL2 ZPD ON (TA.COY=ZPD.COY AND TA.COL2=ZPD.COL2 AND TA.TRXNO=ZPD.TRXNO AND (TA.COL3 = ' ' OR TA.COL3 IS NULL OR TA.COL3 = 'I') AND ZPD.THREADNO=:B1 ) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TA.COL3 = 'Y', TA.USRPRF=:B3 , TA.JOBNM=:B2 , TA.DATIME=LOCALTIMESTAMP

----- End of information for waiting sessions -----
```

So if I get the value of THREADNO =:B1 (this bind parameter) value from .trc file then I can confirm whether these two merge from two sessions are updating the same records or not.

Comment: It should be noted that also *different* values of `THREADNO` *could* cause an update of the same rows. Simple check the count distinct of `THREADNO` in the table `ZPD` grouped by the three join columns.

Comment: select TA.COL2, TA.TRXNO, count(1)  from TABLE_A TA, ZPD_TABL2 ZPD WHERE TA.COY=ZPD.COY AND TA.COL2=ZPD.COL2 AND TA.TRXNO=ZPD.TRXNO having count(1) > 1;--- This itself is giving all unique rows, hence it is unlikely that the two threads would be updating the same records. Anyway, this will need more investigation. What I originally wanted to know is it possible to see the parameter values in .trc file?

Comment: Sorry the idea was a bit different, I added more details in my asnwer.

Comment: Check out [dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_MONITOR.html#GUID-C9054D20-3A70-484F-B11B-CC591A10D609) for enabling trace with bind variable values emitted to the trace file.

Comment: @JeffHolt Thank you and this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One possible *suspect* constalation in your use case would be if the `threadno` is not *uniquely* mapped to the join keys used in the `MERGE`.

You may quickly check it with the query below - it *should not* return any row. If yes, you have a postential problem described later.

```
select COY, COL2, TRXNO, min(THREADNO), max(THREADNO)
from zpd_tabl2 zpd 
group by COY, COL2, TRXNO
having count(distinct THREADNO) > 1;
```

**Bind Variables Used in Dealock Statements**

Well, the deadlock trace file contains some information

```
Peeked Binds
============
  Bind variable information
    position=1
    datatype(code)=2
    datatype(string)=NUMBER
    precision=0
    scale=0
    max length=22
    value=1
```

But this *will not* help you as it is the *peeked* value used while the statement was parsed.

**Rows waited on**

More usefull information is the `rowid` of the rows caused the problem

```
Rows waited on:
  Session 138: obj - rowid = 00012563 - AAASVjAARAAAACbAAB
  (dictionary objn - 75107, file - 17, block - 155, slot - 1)
  Session 12: obj - rowid = 00012563 - AAASVjAARAAAACbAAA
  (dictionary objn - 75107, file - 17, block - 155, slot - 0)
```

The `object_id` (here 75107) should point to your `TABLE_A` and you can check the `threadno`s that try to modify the problematic rows with the following query.

```
select a.rowid, a.COY, a.COL2, a.TRXNO , zpd.threadno
from table_a a 
join zpd_tabl2 zpd
ON ( a.coy = zpd.coy
AND a.col2 = zpd.col2
AND a.trxno = zpd.trxno)
where a.rowid in ( 'AAASVjAARAAAACbAAB','AAASVjAARAAAACbAAA');
```

If you see at least four rows, that you suffer the `threadno`problem stated in the beginning.

**Reproducible Example**

Note, I can't claim that this is exact your situation, but this is the *simplest* way how to get a deadlock you observed.

```
create table table_a as
select rownum coy, rownum col2, rownum trxno, ' ' col3, localtimestamp datime 
from dual
connect by level <= 2;

create table zpd_tabl2 as
select rownum coy, rownum col2, rownum trxno, 1 threadno
from dual
union all
select  rownum coy,  rownum col2,  rownum trxno, 2 threadno
from dual
union all
select 1+rownum coy, 1+rownum col2, 1+rownum trxno, 3 threadno
from dual
union all
select  1+rownum coy,  1+rownum col2,  1+rownum trxno, 4 threadno
from dual
;
```

- in **Session 1** run the `MERGE` with pareter **`1`**

.

```
MERGE  INTO table_a ta
USING zpd_tabl2 zpd ON ( ta.coy = zpd.coy
                         AND ta.col2 = zpd.col2
                         AND ta.trxno = zpd.trxno
                         AND ( ta.col3 = ' '
                               OR ta.col3 IS NULL
                               OR ta.col3 = 'I' )
                         AND zpd.threadno = :b1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET ta.col3 = 'Y',
    ta.datime = localtimestamp;

 1 row merged
```

- in **Session 2** run the `MERGE` with pareter **`4`**

`1 row merged`

- in **Session 1** run the `MERGE` with pareter **`3`**

`waiting`

- in **Session 2** run the `MERGE` with pareter **`1`**

`waiting`

- in **Session 1**

`ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I liked the idea of selecting min(threadno) , max(threadno), but  the first query is not returning any rows so, the only possibility seems the callers threads (say two threads) sending the same thread number in the bind parameter. The row_id, I think gets changed on DB restart. Meantime we have logged this bind parameter so that next time if occurs we will come to know. Thank you.

Comment: ROWID can [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435123/4808122) @dowonderatwill but not on *DB restart*.

Comment: A good starting point is to clarify if the `MERGE` is the only DML of the transaction or if there are other open update or merge statements that can collide with the other threadno (this is what I expect).  @dowonderatwill

Comment: Just an update after above analysis we were sure that there is no code issue, we approached Oracle, and they suggested to increase the initrans, so we took that as the steps and further kept logging.